# Behaviour of a function in differential equation

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

I have the following question, which is says that: 
$$y' - (1/3)y = e^{-t} ,~ y(0) = l ,$$ and it says that $y$ goes to zero as $t$ goes to infinity if $l = -3/4$. How is that?

Comment: Is it anyhow related to _Mathematica_ (a computer system) programming?

Comment: @Artes Oops ! ,  i never thought that "mathematica " is for programming ! i thought that it's just "Math"

Answer (score 1):

This is a [first-order linear ordinary differential equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/First-OrderOrdinaryDifferentialEquation.html) in the form
$$
y'(t)+P(t)y(t)=Q(t).
$$
In our ODE, we have $P(t)=-\dfrac{1}{3}$ and $Q(t)=e^{-t}$. Multiply both sides by
$$
e^{\int P(t)\ dx}=e^{-\int \frac{1}{3}\ dt}=\text{C}e^{-\frac{1}{3}t},
$$
yields
$$
\begin{align}
y'\text{C}e^{-\frac{1}{3}t}-\frac{1}{3}\text{C}e^{-\frac{1}{3}t}y&=\text{C}e^{-\frac{4}{3}t}\\
\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{-\frac{1}{3}t}y\right)&=e^{-\frac{4}{3}t}\\
e^{-\frac{1}{3}t}y&=\int e^{-\frac{4}{3}t}\ dt\\
&=-\frac{3}{4}e^{-\frac{4}{3}t}+\text{K}\\
y(t)&=-\frac{3}{4}e^{-t}+\text{K}e^{\frac{1}{3}t}.
\end{align}
$$
As $t\to\infty$, $y\to0$ then $\text{K}=0$. Thus, the solution of the ODE is
$$
\boxed{\Large\color{blue}{y(t)=-\frac{3}{4}e^{-t}}}
$$
As $t=0$, then $y(0)=-\dfrac{3}{4}$.

$$\\$$

---

$$\large\color{blue}{\text{# }\mathbb{Q.E.D.}\text{ #}}$$

Answer (score 0):

The following Mathematica code will solve your differential equation problem:

```
DSolve[{y'[t] - (1/3)*y[t] == Exp[-t], y[0] == l}, y[t], t]
```

The result is:

> ```
> {{y[t] -> 1/4 E^-t (-3 + 3 E^(4 t/3) + 4 E^(4 t/3) l)}}
> ```

Let's look at the value of the limit of this solution to the differential equation as t goes to infinity with the following code:

```
Limit[1/4 E^-t (-3 + 3 E^(4 t/3) + 4 E^(4 t/3) l), t -> \[Infinity]]
```

The result is:

> ```
> (3 + 4 l) \[Infinity]
> ```

Set the above limit equal to zero and solve for `l`.  `l=-3/4` satisfies the condition.

The back slashes refer to multiplication in the symbolic language when it is copied and pasted into this window.